# How to implement infinite scroll with next_page_token rtk query?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

How to implement infinite scroll with next_page_token rtk query?

```
const { companiesData, isCompaniesLoading, nextPageToken } = useGetCompaniesQuery({
    maxPageSize: innerState.maxPageSize,
    pageToken: innerState.pageToken,
  },
  {
    selectFromResult: ({ data, isLoading }) => ({
      companiesData: data?.data ?? [],
      nextPageToken: data?.nextPageToken,
      isCompaniesLoading: isLoading,
    }),
  })
```